# How do I run my selenium tests with Jenkins/Maven?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I set up Jenkins on my local machine running Ubuntu, pointed it at my jdk, and maven, created a job to run my Selenium tests and gave it the path to the pom.xml in the project, but when I try to run the job, it fails right away.  The console output reads

> Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/new job
>   [new job] $ /usr/share/maven2/bin/mvn -f /pathto/pom.xml -Dtests=firefox_tests.xml -Dreceiver=myemail@myemail.com...You must specify at least one goal or lifecycle phase to perform build steps.  The following list illustrates some commonly used build commands:
>   mvn clean Deletes any build output (e.g. class files or JARs).mvn test...

I'm just not sure how to proceed.  How can I get past this error and get my Selenium tests to run with Jenkins and Maven?  Thanks.

Comment: You are running Maven 2 which is old and deprecated. Please upgrade to Maven 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you hooked the selenium test into the Maven lifecycle?

Normally selenium tests would be executed as part of the integration-test phase, which could be configured with a plugin configuration like below in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${skip.selenium.tests}</skip>
        <parallel>none</parallel>
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>runSeleniumTests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this added to your pom (and all Selenium dependencies in place), you should be able to run the selenium tests with

```
mvn clean integration-test
```

And that is also the command you should specify in your CI server. 
Or if it just asks you for goals to execute, choose: 'clean integration-test'

Comment: That seemed to get me a little closer, but I had to remove the clean goal because it said it failed to clean, and that it failed to delete this or that that it would have liked to. Now now it fails giving this message: Error creating properties files for forking; nested exception is java.io.IOException: No such file or directory.  Maybe it doesn't have the right permissions?  Also  what's up with this latest error message?

Comment: Do i have to mention the runner name in pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

According to your error and output, you are running it as:

```
mvn -f /pathto/pom.xml -Dtests=firefox_tests.xml -Dreceiver=myemail@myemail.com
```

So, there is no any goal what to build here. How are you running it manually? Probably forgotten to run as "mvn test -f ..." ?

Comment: I tried mvn test with and without the -f at the command prompt, and the error "Invalid task 'pom.xml': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal".  Furthermore, how would I get Jenkins to add that if it wasn't doing it already?  As for a build goal, I'm just trying to get my Selenium tests to run and get their output.

Comment: How are you running that? With jenkins maven plugin? If that, you should add "Goals and options" (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/58000129/maven-plugin.png.jpg)